# Duplicate posts in my wp_query

Tags: php, wordpress

hy!
I have a probleme of duplicate posts with my wp_query! 
I have several times, the same articles that appear

My code is :

```
<?php
$do_not_duplicate = array();

$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'category__not_in' => array(
        32
    )
));

if ($query->have_posts()):
    while ($query->have_posts()):
        $query->the_post();
        $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;

        global

        $section_id = get_the_ID($post);
        $tw_categories = get_categories();

        stuff....

    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: I am not sure what is duplicating, because this query returns posts that are not in category `32`. WP_Query returns unique post ids.

Comment: In this request, i want to list all the posts that are not in the category 32.
But I get them 2 times

Comment: Strange, and what would you get if you tried: `$posts_array = get_posts(array('category__not_in' => array(6)));`

Comment: How you know it is  `array(6)`? 
now i have 
I do not have 2 times but many times the articles

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it should have been your `32` :)

Comment: No worry, I had put 32 but I still have the same problem

Comment: Maybe the posts aren't duplicated but you do something wrong with them afterwards. What would happen if (continuing my approach) you'd try to display the post IDs like: `foreach ($posts_array as $item) { echo "id: ". $item->ID . "<br>\n"; }`

Comment: I have 2 times the id that are listed.
It may not be code,
I do a request on postman and I have many times the same id of post.

It's necessary to know  one  post has many categories. But i use SEO yoast for canonical url.

Comment: it's maybe a duplicate content mistake?